# image width not showing exact value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the width of the image but it's alerting zero.

```
var $curimg = $('#banner').find('.img1');
alert($curimg.width()); // alerts 0
```

As I'm working on a slider which is scrolling images so it is confusing for me what wrong with the width of image.

---

Ooops sorry here mistakenly width was typed Width();

Comment: Try with lower case `width`. Also your selector could be `$("#banner .img1")`

Comment: also make sure that the image is loaded

Comment: you can use `$('#banner .img1');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one sure problem : it's `width`, not `Width`, JavaScript is case sensitive.

Now, supposing you use `width` and you get 0, then your image is probably not yet loaded. You may wait for your page's images to be loaded using `load` :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $curimg = $('#banner').find('.img1');
    alert($curimg.width());
});
```

Comment: I think you want `$(window).load(fn)`, not `document.body`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes. But it's CW, so you could have directly edited ;)

Comment: @dystroy - I wasn't positive that `document.body` wouldn't work (you never know what jQuery does under the hood sometimes) so thus a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $curimg = $('.img1','#banner');
alert($curimg.width());
```